# Annotations for scala class to use mapper

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver, mapper

I am using DataStax driver to connect to Cassandra database from my Scala application. The driver comes with com.datastax.driver.mapping to map the database table to the corresponding entity class.

I intend to use the mapper like this:

```
def SelectOperationUsingMapper()={
try{
  val session = cluster.connect()
  val manager = new MappingManager(session);
  val mapper = manager.mapper(classOf[User])
  val result= mapper.get("@ned")
  print(result.Name)
}
finally{
  cluster.close()
}
```

}

The Entity `User` is mapped to the database using `@Table` annotation like this:

```
abstract class BusinessEntity

@Table(keyspace="MySpace", name="User")
case class User(userId:String, emailId:String, name:String, description:String, password:String, country:String, joinedDate:Date) extends BusinessEntity{
  @PartitionKey
  @Column(name = "UserId")
  val UserId= userId
  @Column(name = "EmailId")
  val EmailId= emailId
  @Column(name = "Name")
  val Name= name
  @Column(name = "Description")
  val Description= description
  @Column(name = "Password")
  val Password= password
  @Column(name = "Country")
  val Country= country
  @Column(name = "JoinedDate")
  val JoinedDate= joinedDate
}
```

I receive a error message saying No getter or setter method found for Field UserId.

I found an example java code for the similar annotation example and it works fine:

```
 @Table(keyspace = "accounts", name = "users")
public class User {  
    private int id;
    @Column( name = "account_id" )
    private int accountId;
    private String name;
    @Column( name = "creation_date" )
    private Date creationDate;
```

My doubt, is there no way to use the `@Table` annotation in scala code? If yes, where did i go wrong?

> PS: I tried implementing the case class user without body and
>   providing the annotations on top of parameters. Even that gave the
>   same error message.

Comment: I'm no Scala expert, but I think that fields of a case class cannot be edited, except the case they are declared as `var` (which feels to me like defending the purpose of the case class).

Comment: Don't you have to have setters though, even in Java example, I believe they might have setters for them in the User class. At least that's how I used to write Cassandra mapped entities.

Comment: Try Phantom or Quill instead of Java driver. Or [annotate your case class fields with BeanProperty](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-javabeans-beanproperty-annotation) to get Java-style get/set methods